java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
Im running airflow V2.9.1, spark V3.4.2, minio, hive, trino by docker, each service i create a separate docker-compose file
here is my dag file:
import os
from datetime import datetime, date
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.apache.spark.operators.spark_submit import SparkSubmitOperator
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
from datetime import date, datetime

region_list = ["CA", "DE", "FR", "GB", "IN", "JP", "KR", "MX", "RU", "US"]

with DAG(
        dag_id="youtube_trend",
        start_date=datetime(year=2022, month=11, day=4),
        schedule_interval=None,
        catchup=False
) as dag:
    # Start task
    task_start = DummyOperator(
        task_id="Start",
    )

    # End task
    task_end = DummyOperator(
        task_id="End",
    )

    for region in region_list:
        task_clean_data = SparkSubmitOperator(
            task_id=f"clean_data_region_{region}",
            conn_id="apache_spark_master",
            application="/opt/airflow/applications/youtube_trend_clean_data.py",
            application_args=[f"{region}"],
            # jars="/opt/bitnami/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-3.3.4.jar"
        )

        task_start >> task_clean_data >> task_end


here is my application file:
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://nginx:9000")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "minio")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "minio")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", True)
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
conf.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false")

conf.set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "hive")
conf.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
conf.set("spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://hive-metastore:9083")

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).appName('clean_youtube_trend_data').getOrCreate()

# region = 'US'
region = sys.argv[1]

create_table_query = """
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS youtube_videos (
    video_id STRING,
    title STRING,
    channel_title STRING,
    category_title STRING,
    publish_time STRING,
    trending_date STRING,
    views INT,
    likes INT,
    dislikes INT,
    comment_count INT
)
PARTITIONED BY (region STRING, year INT, month INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\\""
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3a://youtube-trend-cleansed/_data/';"""

# print(create_table_query)
spark.sql(create_table_query)

json_file_path = f's3a://youtube-trend-raw/{region}/{region}_category_id.json'
json_category_df = spark.read.option('multiline', 'true').json(json_file_path)
items_df = json_category_df.select(explode('items').alias('item'))

category_df = items_df \
    .select(
    items_df['item.id'].cast('int').alias('id'),
    items_df['item.snippet.title'].alias('category_title')) \
    .orderBy('id')
category_df.show()

video_df = spark.read \
    .options(delimiter=",", header=True) \
    .option("multiline", "true") \
    .option("quote", '"') \
    .option("escape", '"') \
    .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", True) \
    .option("inferSchema", True) \
    .csv(f's3a://youtube-trend-raw/{region}/*.csv')

video_df = video_df.select("video_id", "title", "channel_title", "category_id",
                           col("publish_time").cast("date").alias("publish_time"),
                           "trending_date", "views", "likes", "dislikes", "comment_count") \
    .withColumn("title", trim(col("title"))) \
    .withColumn("region", lit(region)) \
    .withColumn('year', year('publish_time')) \
    .withColumn('month', month('publish_time')) \
    .withColumn("trending_date", to_date(video_df["trending_date"], "yy.dd.MM"))
video_df = video_df.join(category_df, category_df['id'] == video_df.category_id, 'inner')
video_df = video_df.drop("id", "category_id").na.drop()

video_df \
    .select("video_id", "title", "channel_title", "category_title", "publish_time", "trending_date",
            "views", "likes", "dislikes", "comment_count", "region", "year", "month") \
    .write \
    .format('hive') \
    .mode('overwrite').insertInto("youtube_videos")

spark.stop()
print("done")

when i use airflow to submit job to spark, it work well with create table:
create_table_query = """
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS youtube_videos (
    video_id STRING,
    title STRING,
    channel_title STRING,
    category_title STRING,
    publish_time STRING,
    trending_date STRING,
    views INT,
    likes INT,
    dislikes INT,
    comment_count INT
)
PARTITIONED BY (region STRING, year INT, month INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\\""
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3a://youtube-trend-cleansed/_data/';"""

# print(create_table_query)
spark.sql(create_table_query)

but in the line
json_file_path = f's3a://youtube-trend-raw/{region}/{region}_category_id.json'
json_category_df = spark.read.option('multiline', 'true').json(json_file_path)

it log the error at airflow task:
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2688)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3431)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:53)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:362)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2592)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - ... 26 more
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/05/13 04:24:38 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20240513042434-0001/0 on worker-20240513042407-172.19.0.12-35297 (172.19.0.12:35297) with 1 core(s)
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/05/13 04:24:38 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20240513042434-0001/0 on hostPort 172.19.0.12:35297 with 1 core(s), 1024.0 MiB RAM
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - File "/opt/***/applications/youtube_trend_clean_data.py", line 47, in <module>
[2024-05-13, 04:24:38 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - json_category_df = spark.read.option('multiline', 'true').json(json_file_path)

i checked that in spark container /opt/bitnami/spark/jars also contain jar files:
aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.262.jars, hadoop-aws-3.3.4.jar
how can i resolve this problem
spark can find all the jars needed to connect, read fil from minio
